# Sidekiq memory leak on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-leaks, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq 4.1.2 as background job processor on Heroku (with Heroku Redis 3.2.0).

Problem is, Sidekiq process consumes more memory with every minute and never goes down. Sometimes it takes just 10 minutes to grow from 300Mb to 2Gb (then it dies, horribly).
Of course, my first thought was "Oh, looks like I've screwed up my background job's memory management!".

The nature of my background jobs is that they take a long time to complete, and they create a lot of objects, which are saved to DB and not used again. So I've added periodic manual garbage collector calls: `GC.start` after every 1000 objects processed.

I tested it on my local machine and was relieved: Sidekiq process with 10 threads was staying under 500Mb.
Then I deployed this code on Heroku, but, alas, Sidekiq's insatiable hunger for memory was still in place: memory consumption only increases and never decreases, despite periodic manual starts of garbage collector.

Therefore, problem is following: same code does not leak on my machine, but does leak on Heroku. What may cause such behavior? What should I do to pinpoint it?

Comment: Are you sure the code is thread safe? Could be worth taking a look at https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting

Comment: Are you running Ruby 2.1 on Heroku?

Comment: I had a similar problem the other day that made me think it was sidekiq however it ended up being my assets loaded in an order that led to a massive leak.  I would say if it's working on your local then there is something in your production config. that's somehow leading to this issue.  For me it was that assets get precompiled and thus the order was changed.  For you it will be something else but approaching it from that mindset might help you.

Comment: Code is thread safe. Each job processes its own subset of data, these subsets do not intersect. Ruby version is 2.3.0. Thanks for the tip, @bkunzi01, I'll try to run sidekiq in production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was one of the gems in the `:production` group. I was using it for profiling, and looks like it did a poor job of it. I've replaced it with a similar gem and now there's no memory leak.